# Make XPath stop at a certain depth?

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML

```
<span class="medium bold day-time-clock">
            09:00
            <div class="tooltip-box first-free-tip ">
                <div class="tooltip-box-inner">
                    <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
                    Some more text
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
```

I want an XPath that only gets the text *09:00*, not *Some more text* NOT using `text()[1]` because that causes other problems. My current XPath looks like this

```
("//span[1][contains(@class, 'day-time-clock')]/text()")
```

I want one that ignores this whole part of the HTML

```
    <div class="tooltip-box first-free-tip ">
        <div class="tooltip-box-inner">
            <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
            Some more text
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `//span[1][contains(@class, 'day-time-clock')]/text()` **won't match `Some more text`**! Note that `/text()` might select **child** text node only while `"Some more text"` is **descendant** text node... Can you share little more details as for now your issue is quite unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the level of `descendant::` nodes with `position()`.
So the following expression does work:

```
span/descendant::node()[2 > position()]
```

Adjust the number in the predicate to your needs, `2` is only an example. A disadvantage of this approach is that the counting of the descendants is only accurate for the first child in the descending tree.

---

Another approach is limiting the both: the ancestors and the descendants:

```
span/descendant::node()[3 > count(ancestor::*) and 1 > count(descendant::*)]
```

Here, too, you have to adjust the numbers in the predicates to get any useful results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `normalize-space()` for select all non-whitespace nodes of the document:

`//span[contains(@class, 'day-time-clock')]/text()[normalize-space()]`

Comment: But the second node have content in it, that is, it is not a white space node. I don't understand your answer?

Comment: Each child tag in the text-node of parent tag is separator for the text-node of the parent tag, herewith a content of the nested tags is ignored. Accordingly, the number of text nodes in the tag is **n + 1**, where **n** is number of tags from first level of nesting. In the current case there is only one non-empty text-node.

Answer (score 0):

I think (if I understand you correctly) that

```
"..//div[contains(@class, 'tooltip-box')]/parent::span"
```

gets you there.